# Is it possible to access date range values in aggregation scripts in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm combining a scripted_metric with date ranges in an ElasticSearch (2.4) aaggregation.

So if I understand correctly, the scripts (init, map, combine, reduce) will be applied for every date range specified. Correct?

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "aggs": {
        "kpi_over_time": {
            "aggs": {
                "profit": {
                    "scripted_metric": {
                        "init_script": "",
                        "map_script": "",
                        "combine_script": "",
                        "reduce_script": ""
                    }
                }
            },
            "date_range": {
                "field": "date",
                "ranges": [{
                        "from": "2017-09-01||-12M",
                        "to": "2017-09-01"
                    },
                    {
                        "from": "2017-10-01||-12M",
                        "to": "2017-10-01"
                    },
                    {
                        "from": "2017-11-01||-12M",
                        "to": "2017-11-01"
                    },
                    {
                        "from": "2017-12-01||-12M",
                        "to": "2017-12-01"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to access the "from" and "to" of the computed date range in the scripted_metric scripts?

For example, would it be possible, in the "init_script" to have something like

`_agg["from"] = <something_about_the current_date_range_query>["from"]`